# Eclipse on High Sierra - white scrollbars for dark theme

Tags: eclipse, macos, macos-high-sierra, eclipse-2019-12

I have problem with setting completely dark theme in Eclipse 2019-12 for scrollbars (screen attached) - does someone know how to fix it?
[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that I found the solution for this issue. 
To fix it - I had to add parameter to eclipse.ini as a last line.

`-Dswt.enable.themedScrollBar=true`

`eclipse.ini` localization:
Right click on: eclipse -> show package contents
go to `Contents/Eclipse/eclipse.ini`

I've also installed Color IDE Pack, but I'm not sure that it influences on solution